# How can I encrypt a string using public key to generate a static string rather than a dynamic one in php?

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I am trying to encrypt a string using a public key but each time I get a new string. Any workarounds to getting a static string?

Here is my code

```
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents("file://C:/Users/nick/Dropbox/wamp/www/samples/mycert.cer"));
$plaintext = "Matr!x12";
openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
echo base64_encode($encrypted);
```

Comment: Why do you want to get a static string?

Comment: Does the result change on each request?

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously SSL encryption generates different results each time it's involved for security reasons. If you for whatever reason you need to have identical results multiple times you cannot use "real encryption". Maybe just use MD5 or some other hash function but be aware that you cannot get secrets that cannot be decrypted (with enough effort).